# Why does this aggregation query work in MongoDB from command line but not through MongoEngine?

Tags: django, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

I have a query which runs as expected when it's directly executed in MongoDB, but I'm facing some troubles trying to make it work through MongoEngine.

**DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT**

1. MongoDB 3.0.7
2. Mongoengine 0.10
3. Pymongo 3.1
4. Django 1.8.4

**ORIGINAL QUERY**

This query performs perfectly in MongoDB when executed from command line, retrieving lots of results.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {
         "variant":1,
         "version":1,
         "date":1,
           "quarter":{$cond:[{$lte:[{$month:"$date"},3]},
                        "Q1",
                        {$cond:[{$lte:[{$month:"$date"},6]},
                                "Q2",
                                {$cond:[{$lte:[{$month:"$date"},9]},
                                        "Q3",
                                        "Q4"]}]}]}}},{$group:{"_id":{"quarter":"$quarter", "year":{$year:"$date"}},
  "total":{$sum:1},
  "details":{$push:{
     variant:"$variant",
     version:"$version",
     date:"$date" }}}}])
```

**MONGOENGINE QUERY**

This is my attempt to make it work in MongoEngine.
It throws a "pipeline element 1 is not an object" error.

```
Collection.objects.aggregate([{"$project": {
        "variant":1,
        "version":1,
        "date":1,
        "quarter":{"$cond":[{"$lte":[{"$month":"$date"},3]},
                    "Q1",
                    {"$cond":[{"$lte":[{"$month":"$date"},6]},
                          "Q2",
                          {"$cond":[{"$lte":[{"$month":"$date"},9]},
                                "Q3",
                                "Q4"]}]}]}}},
  {"$group":{"_id":{"quarter":"$quarter", "year":{"$year":"$date"}},
     "total":{"$sum":1},
     "details":{"$push":{
        "variant":"$variant",
        "version":"$version",
        "date":"$date"   }}}}])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to remove the brackets and pass comma separated parameters to the aggregate method.

```
project = {"$project": {
        "variant":1,
        "version":1,
        "date":1,
        "quarter":{"$cond":[{"$lte":[{"$month":"$date"},3]},
                    "Q1",
                    {"$cond":[{"$lte":[{"$month":"$date"},6]},
                          "Q2",
                          {"$cond":[{"$lte":[{"$month":"$date"},9]},
                                "Q3",
                                "Q4"]}]}]}}}
group = {"$group":{"_id":{"quarter":"$quarter", "year":{"$year":"$date"}},
     "total":{"$sum":1},
     "details":{"$push":{
        "variant":"$variant",
        "version":"$version",
        "date":"$date" }}}}

queryset = Collection.objects.aggregate( project, group )
```